# Can a Macro with a goto statement and a label be defined?

Tags: c++, c

Can a **Macro** with a **goto** statement and a **label** be defined?

Comment: You can define your whole program as one huge macro if you are mad enough to do that.

Comment: How is this question unclear?

Comment: The real question is why you'd want to do so

Comment: `#define macro int main(void) { goto end; end: return 0; }`

Comment: @NPE Unclear is often used as a catch all close reason. Here the answer is so obvious that one wonders how the asker doesn't know the answer. So one suspects that there is some missing detail. You'd write the obvious answer and asker would say, "yes, but I'm trying to do this" and then supply the detail that changes the question.

Comment: now I got what you mean, sorry for having cast my close-vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A macro is a textual substitution taken care by the preprocessor so, yes you can. You can define a macro for a goto statement and/or a label.

*Ps. anyway that's a terrible practice.. both using lots of macros and using gotos*

```
#include <iostream>

#define GOTOSTMT goto helloworld;
#define LABELSTMT helloworld:

int main() {
    
    int i = 0;
    
    LABELSTMT
    
    std::cout << "Don't ever program like this" << std::endl;
    i++;
    if(i < 3)
        GOTOSTMT
   
}
```

Comment: I had a good laugh at the irony of answering a S.O. question with `"Don't ever program like this"` as part of the answer.